# Check if an hour is between 2 time periods - React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating an Auto-Logout functionality (which needs to be logged out every day at 9 am) in my react-native app, so for that I came up with the logic:

So what I'm doing is, lets say I have my parent stack component, in that inside the useEffect, suppose the app is just opened, I will check if I have `lastRunTime` saved in `async-storage`, if true, then I will create a new Date object pointing today's current date, then if 9:00 am comes in between these 2 times, I will logout and set lastRunTime as `Date.now().toString()` in `async-storage`.

```js
// auto-logout at 9 am everyday
  useEffect(() => {
    const lastRunTime = AsynStorage.getItem('lastRunTime');
    if (lastRunTime) {
      const justOpened = new Date();
      const lastOpened = new Date(lastRunTime);
      if (9 <= justOpened.getHours() && 9 >= lastOpened.getHours()) {
        logout();
        AsynStorage.setItem('lastRunTime', now.toString());
      }
    } else {
      console.log('9 am not in time range');
      AsynStorage.setItem('lastRunTime', new Date().toString());
    }
  }, []);
```

But it is not giving the correct result, always printing `console.log('9 am not in time range');` even though I provided yesterday's date and `Date.now()`.

```
const lastOpened = new Date(2022, 1, 21, 18, 0); // yesterday's 6 pm
const justOpened = new Date(); // right now

// now obviously today's 9 am was in between the 2 time intervals, but still it logs: console.log('9 am not in time range');
```

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Possible solutions

First of all, just to clarify, `useEffect(() => {...}, [])` only runs once, when you create the component. It can be considered as an equivalent of `componentDidMount` from older terminology.

So, if you want to log the user out at 9, if the user opens your app at 8:59 and waits until 9:01, they won't be logged out, because `useEffect` ran at `8:59`. You could solve this issue with any kind of interval and periodically check if time is past 9:00.

The most ideal solution would be is to handle this logout feature backend side, if you have control over the backend, as that has most certainty that if backend is online and logic is correct, your user will be logged out.

The second most ideal solution would be is to have some kind of background task scheduled in your app, that makes sure that the user is logged out, regardless if your app is open.

The third most ideal solution is to use some kind of interval as I've explained above but that only works if the app is open.

#### Problem with your current code:

```js
if (9 <= justOpened.getHours() && 9 >= lastOpened.getHours()) {
```

This if is incorrect, because let's say, lastOpened.getHours is `17` (I opened the app yesterday at 17:00), I won't be logged out, because `9 >= 17` is `false`. You could use some date handling library like `date-fns` or `moment` (less recommended because of not using plain Date objects) to make date handling easier, check if your current date is after today's 9:00 and if your `lastRunTime` is before your current date.

Comment: Yes, actually I was comparing to 9 straightforward which was wrong, so first I got today's 9 am using the Date object, then simply checked `if (justOpened > nineAmToday && lastOpened < nineAmToday)` and this is working for now. For the later, I guess firebase cloud function could be good option? like it will trigger a function and send a notification to user which will contain a parameter let's say `{data: logout}`, or maybe a node server...

Comment: Firebase cloud function could be an option, depends on your backend. The main thing is: don't let the app to control logout. Let the backend control logout, and let the app always send the stored token, if the token is valid, it will work, if the token is invalid, redirect the user to login page.

Comment: Actually, the api I'm using expires in 6 hours, (it's a trading app, so the market starts at 9:30 am to 3:30 pm), and in that api there is no way I could check beforehand if the token is expired, it only throws exception when I place an order. So that is why...